# How can i utilize the Event Grid for work item change event in VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I think i am really thinking over the board. We are migrating form TFS to VSTS and we have an integration developed in c# that actually sends data from service now to TFS and TFS to ServiceNow. We have decided to use Event Grid to get the notifications from VSTS(Azure Dev Ops) when any work item got changed. Can somebody suggest if this possible and help on how to implement it if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can directly get an event grid notification from Azure DevOps.

Instead setup a service hook to trigger when any work item gets changed. You can handle this in many different ways, but perhaps as an Azure Function (https://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1341/service-hooks-vsts-azure-function) might be a good idea as it's serverless like Azure Event Grid.

You could then trigger a custom event into Azure Event Grid from your function if you already have code to work with topics in the grid. (e.g. http://www.biztalkgurus.com/blogs/msft-biztalk-community/sending-custom-events-to-azure-event-grid/).